# Upgrade to Unity container throwing "COMException: Retrieving the COM class factory"

Tags: c#, unity-container

I have recently upgraded my project Unity Container to 5.11.10 version and below is the code

```
using CommonServiceLocator;
using Unity;
using Unity.Injection;
using Unity.Lifetime;
using Unity.ServiceLocation;

var container = new UnityContainer();
var locator = new UnityServiceLocator(container);
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => locator);
container.RegisterType(typeof(myclass));
var instance = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance(myclass);
```

The code is throwing below error while referring myclass (`var instance`... is in another project though) , all the projects targets are set to x86

```
CommonServiceLocator.ActivationException: 'Activation error occurred while trying to get instance of type myclass, key ""'
COMException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {01DFEFEE-D2DA-4F55-AA57-746A3DFB3151} 
failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] - code that is currently in the post is extremely unlikely to produce such error on its own as Unity does not use any COM registrations as far as I know.